# Recursive query for Postgres with json datatype

Tags: json, database, postgresql, recursive-query, postgresql-9.6

The current structure of the table has two columns which has type as an integer and a json.

The JSON is unstructured and it can have any nesting level. Each JSON document can be parent or child which is indicated by `level` field. 
If the `level` is `parent` it can contain either another `parent` node or `child` node. 
If `level` is `child` then it's the leaf node of the JSON.

The nesting of nodes can be `n`

I'm trying to write a query, where I need all `child` node with a specific condition.

The approach I am taking is:

1. Find all `child` nodes recursively.Basically flat structure of all child nodes
2. Then do a projection on those `child` nodes.

The sample table for this can be found here: 
[SqlFiddleLink](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4acdf/3)

The JSON which is used above can be found here: 
[Sample JSON Structure](https://jsonblob.com/0df981dc-6c92-11e7-a38a-f7c2f55aee83)

The query I have written works when the level of child is just one level but it does not work for nesting till level `n`

The query which is working till level 1 is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE x ( c ) AS (

Select *  from 
json_array_elements((select info FROM Controls where ID='111'))c
where  c ->>'level' = 'child'

UNION ALL

select json_array_elements(
(    
Select parent_control->'controls' controls from   
json_array_elements((select info FROM Controls where 
ID='111'))parent_control
where parent_control ->>'level' = 'parent'
))

)select c->>'unique_tag' as unique_tag, c ->>'values' as values from x
```

I might be missing out very small thing here, I'm banging my head to make this work till any nested level. Any help is appreciated.

In SqlFiddle, I have two rows entered. 
The ID with `111` has one level of nesting and query works with that. 
However, ID with `110` has nested level of structure and it just returns parent element where I expect it to return child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion should be based on the column `value->'controls'`, which explicitly creates a recursive structure in the json column:

```
with recursive rec_controls(id, unique_tag, controls, level) as (
    select id, value->>'unique_tag', value->'controls', value->>'level'
    from controls, json_array_elements(info)
union all
    select id, value->>'unique_tag', value->'controls', value->>'level'
    from rec_controls, json_array_elements(controls)
)
select id, unique_tag
from rec_controls
where level = 'child'
order by 1, 2;

 id  | unique_tag 
-----+------------
 110 | child_1
 110 | child_2
 110 | child_3
 111 | 1
 111 | 2
 111 | 4
 111 | 5
 111 | 6
 111 | 8
(9 rows)
```

Comment: This works till any nested level. After looking at this, I actually understood 

```WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t
)
SELECT n FROM t LIMIT 100;```